# Sox - concating multiple files with added padding between each

Tags: audio, sox

I am new to Sox and was unable to find a way to do this so I'll be specific.

- I use Windows 7
- I have a batch of 94 .au files, each containing a spoken sentence (from the text of a language learning tool). They're named 00.au, 01.au, etc.
- I can concat them easily with sox with just the following: sox.exe *.au complete.wav
- The finished file plays them all in order and so far so good, but the original files have all silence between sentences removed, which means that sentence 2 starts immediately after sentence 1 etc., giving a very rushed and unnatural sound, and it's hard to follow.
- I have tried some variations on the pad command but without success. What I would love to do is concat the files, while adding 0.5 seconds of silence between EACH original .au file

Does anyone know if this is possible, either with a script or by just one clever line? I don't understand the pad or delay enough.

Answer (score 1):

After sleeping on it and Googling how to write batch files, I came up with a dirty way to do it:

```
for %%x in (*.au) do e:\sox\sox.exe %%x %%x.wav pad 0 1

e:\sox\sox.exe *.wav complete.wav

for %%y in (*au.wav) do del %%y
```

It does create a bunch of intermediary wave files called 01.au.wav etc. that it removes afterwards, maybe not elegant but it works.